# pyautogui.FailSafeException: error executing pyautogui on a server

Tags: python, automation, pyautogui, rpa

I'm trying to run a Python automation on a server, scheduled to run at specific times.

When I am logged in the session, the application runs perfectly, executing all functions. When I don't have the session open remotely, an error occurs when trying to execute the function `pyautogui.hotkey ('firstKey', 'secondKey')`.

Apparently, when I'm not logged in remotely, internally the system leaves the mouse positioned top/left, and this is a "stop" parameter of the pyautogui.

I changed the parameter `pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False` so that this stop does not occur. When I put this code, the FAILSAFE error is not displayed, but the function still does not work.

Can you help me?

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:12064/devtools/browser/12c193a2-e734-46a0-9ab5-73af9675b6a8
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "netProject.py", line 47, in <module>
    pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl","v")
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 988, in hotkey
    _failSafeCheck()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 1010, in _failSafeCheck
    raise FailSafeException('PyAutoGUI fail-safe triggered from mouse moving to upper-left corner. To disable this fail-safe, set pyautogui.FAILSAFE to False.')
pyautogui.FailSafeException: PyAutoGUI fail-safe triggered from mouse moving to upper-left corner. To disable this fail-safe, set pyautogui.FAILSAFE to False.
```

Comment: Try to translate your question, this is an english community, most people can't help you on questions in an other language.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because spanish

Comment: I'm trying to run a python automation on a server When I am logged in the session, the application runs perfectly. When I don't have the session open remotely, an error occurs when trying to execute the function ```pyautogui.hotkey ('firstKey', 'secondKey')```.